# How to calculate $P(X+Y=2 | Y = 1)$

Tags: probability

I know this might be an easy question but i completely forgot how to calculate this. In the exercise we have the following information:

- $P_x(0) = 6/20$
- $P_x(1) = 7/20$
- $P_x(2) = 7/20$
- $P_y(0) = 9/20$
- $P_y(1) = 6/20$
- $P_y(2) = 5/20$

Hope you guys can help me :P

Comment: Hint:
$P(X + Y\  |\  Y = 1) = P(X + 1 = 2\  | \ Y = 1)$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? What do you usually do with such problems?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ assumes independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(X+Y=2 \mid Y=1) = \frac{P(X+Y=2, Y=1)}{P(Y=1)} $$

$$= \frac{P(X=1,Y=1)}{P(Y=1)} = \frac{P(X=1)P(Y=1)}{P(Y=1)} = P(X=1) = 7/20$$

Here I assumed that $X,Y$ are independent random variables. Otherwise there is not enough information to solve the problem.

Indeed, in general information about the marginal distributions is not enough to determine the joint distribution.